# Silverlight Command binding issue for controls

Tags: silverlight, binding, command, prism, icommand

I am creating command to useing in silverlight xaml bindings. But the command are not working outside the Controls.

I am usinf ESRI silverlight API. API has a control named map.

```
public sealed class Map : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{}
```

There is a layer in this API that named FeatureLayer but this not inherits from Control class.

```
public class FeatureLayer : GraphicsLayer, IAttribution
{}
```

I am using these in xaml like this.

```
        xmlns:esri="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client" 
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:Infrastructure.Commands;assembly=Infrastructure" 
    xmlns:fcmd="clr-namespace:Infrastructure.Commands.FeatureLayerCommands;assembly=Infrastructure"  

   <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              cmd:MouseClick.Command="{Binding Map_Click}" 
              cmd:SizeChange.Command="{Binding Size_Change}"
              >

        <esri:FeatureLayer ID="ff"                               
                           Mode="OnDemand"
                           fcmd:FeatureLayerMouseEnter.Command="{Binding FeatureLayerCommand}"
                           />

    </esri:Map>
```

In this stuation, the

```
 cmd:MouseClick.Command="{Binding Map_Click}" 
              cmd:SizeChange.Command="{Binding Size_Change}"
```

commands are working but,

```
 fcmd:FeatureLayerMouseEnter.Command="{Binding FeatureLayerCommand}"
```

command is not working.What is the problem?

Comment: When running have you checked the Output window for binding errors?

Comment: Output Window Errors are: 
The thread '<No Name>' (0x16b8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1d0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x5b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x107c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x11b4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x39c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x12e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x264) has exited with code 0 (0x0).